# Moving files and leaving links in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

The objective of this code is to create a command that move files and leaves links in their place. I'm just a beginner in shell scripting and it would be quite useful to hear your opinions on how to improve my code.

I already used https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check my code.

## Questions

I change directory several times because I was creating broken links with relative paths. Is there a better way to do this?

Is there a better way to get the path of the files than to use `cut` with `wc` and using `cd` and `pwd`?

## mvln.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ];then 
    echo -e "mvln: Move file and leave a link in its place\\nUse: mvln [TARGET] [DIRECTORY]";
    exit 1;
fi

pathTo=$(cut -d ' ' -f "$#" <<< "$*"); 
if ! [ -d "$pathTo" ]; then
    echo "mvln: $pathTo is not a directory";
    exit 1;
fi

pathOriginal=$(pwd);
cd "$pathTo" || exit 1;
pathTo=$(pwd);
cd "$pathOriginal" || exit 1;

files=$(cut -d ' ' -f -$(("$#" - 1)) <<< "$*");

for i in $files;
do 
    if [ "$i" -ef "$pathTo" ]; then
        echo "mvln: '$pathFrom' and '$pathTo' are the same file";
        continue;
    fi
    wordCount=$(tr -t '/' ' ' <<< "$i" | wc -w);
    pathFrom=$(cut -d '/' -f -$((wordCount - 1)) <<< "$i");
    file=$(cut -d '/' -f "$wordCount" <<< "$i");
    mv "$i" "$pathTo" || continue;
    cd "$pathFrom" || exit 1;
    ln -s "$pathTo/$file" ".";
    cd "$pathOriginal" || exit 1
done;
exit 0;
```

---

## Creating test files

```
mkdir ~/Documentos ~/Scripts ~/Scripts/test ~/Scripts/test/ln
touch ~/arqHome.txt ~/Documentos/arqDoc.txt ~/Scripts/arqScripts.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq1.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq2.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq3.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq4.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq5.txt
```

## Examples of how the command works:

- ### Example1

  Move all files from 1 place

  ```
  bash mvln.sh ~/Scripts/test/arq* ~/Scripts/test/ln
  ```
- ### Example2

  Move files from several places

  ```
  bash mvln.sh ~/arqHome.txt ~/Documentos/arqDoc.txt ~/Scripts/arqScripts.txt ~/Scripts/test/arq* ~/Scripts/test/ln
  ```

Comment: Version 2 added!

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of temporarily changing directories, you can call [`realpath`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath) to get the absolute path to a directory. There is also [`readlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) which does similar job.

---

To generate the `files` array:

```
files=("$@"); unset "files[-1]"
```

---

The rest looks okay to me. However, keep your usage of `;` consistent. If you are using it, put them in each statement; otherwise skip it altogether.

Comment: Thanks! That `unset files[-1]` tip seems interenting!

Comment: what is the diference from `files=("$@");` and `files=$("$@");`?

Answer (score 1):

## Turn on more error-checking

I always find it useful to error out on undefined variables or command failures in Bash scripts:

```
set -eu
```

## Omit unnecessary statement separators

Most of the `;` (at end of line) are not needed, and just add visual clutter.

## Options to `echo` are not portable

Instead of `echo -e`, consider using multiple `echo` commands, `printf`, or `$''` quoting instead.

## Error messages should go to the error stream

Just add `>&2` to the commands that print error/warning messages.  I like to define a short function for this:

```
die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

We can use `$0` for the program name (as used) rather than hard-coding a name.

## Consider `ln -r` to create relative symlinks

Instead of changing working directory as you go (which, as you have found, is inconvenient and confusing), take advantage of your `ln` implementation.  In particular the `-r` or `--relative` option does what you want (though you might want to avoid this if the user supplied an absolute pathname).

## Use bash array variables to hold lists of names

The current handling of arguments doesn't work very well for filenames containing newlines or spaces.  That can be improved using array variables.

## Use variable-expansion to transform filenames

`wordCount` is unreliable for names containing spaces.  The Bash idiom to remove everything up to and including the last `/` from a variable called `i` is `${i##*/}`.

## Let `mv` and `ln` check for errors

Instead of testing whether target file is the same as source, just rely on `mv` to provide its own error message, and use the return value to see whether it succeeded.

## Return non-zero if any of the operations failed

Only return a true (zero) code if everything the user asked for has been done.

---

## Modified version

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

test "$#" -ge 2 \
    || die "$0: Move file and leave a link in its place" \
           "Usage: $0 TARGET... DIRECTORY" \
           "Copy each TARGET into DIRECTORY, and replace it with a symlink."

src=("$@")

dest="${src[-1]}"
test -d "$dest" || die "$0: $dest is not a directory"

unset src[-1]

result=true

for i in "${src[@]}"
do
    mv -t "$dest" "$i" && ln -srT "$dest/${i##*/}" "$i" || result=false
done

$result
```